# Searching by Poster's Rep

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, search

Is there currently a feature that allows one to search by rep? Say, if I wanted to find all posts by users with <= 50 rep and with 0 votes, can this be done with the current search engine architecture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SO is content-driven. You can search for questions with 0 votes, but not for users. But you can search the posts of a specific user. Have a look [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=).