# Can you sort results from all sites (stackexchange.com/search)? If so, how? If not, why not?

Tags: support, search, stackexchange.com, sorting

On most SE sites, you can sort search results:

[image: Search result sort bar]

However, this sort bar appears to be missing on ["search all sites"](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=*&pagesize=50).

Is there any simple way to sort results from all sites?

Comment: [How can I sort questions by date(s) on the all-Stack Exchange search results page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357909/how-can-i-sort-questions-by-dates-on-the-all-stack-exchange-search-results-pag)