# Add a way to sort results by date on https://stackexchange.com/search

Tags: feature-request, search, stackexchange.com, sorting

Feature request: add a way to sort results by date on https://stackexchange.com/search (e.g., date of post and date of last activity).

Comment: Related: [Can you sort results from all sites (stackexchange.com/search)? If so, how? If not, why not?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371604/can-you-sort-results-from-all-sites-stackexchange-com-search-if-so-how-if-n). (That one just asked if that's possible)

Comment: In my [answer to: "How can I sort questions by date(s) on the all-Stack Exchange search results page?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357931/271271), I provided a bookmarklet which will sort the results *within a page* of the search results provided by searches on the main Stack Exchange site. While it's not the same as having the server sort the results by date, I do find it helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like a reasonable request. Depending on your situation, however, you may be able to use [date range search operators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching) instead:

- For the most recently active posts: `lastactive:7d..`
- For older posts: `created:..5y`
- Created before this answer but after the question: `created:2023-01-10..2023-01-27`

This can get you pretty far, especially if you change the dates while searching to break results into more manageable chunks, though it's not very intuitive for the average user.